# Which files must be included to build Kendo grid in MVC4

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use Ken UI as my data grid style
But I was struggled in the beginning step, I can not even establish a new Kendo object
I had done like following including files in BundleConfig

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/kendo/2013.1.319").Include(
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/jquery.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.web.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.grid.min.js",
        "~/Scrip`enter code here`ts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.calendar.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.data.min.js"
        ));
```

and Layout page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Script/kendo/2013.1.319")
```

with above code I still can declare Kendo Object
Do I miss something to include?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#using-kendo-ui-in-asp.net-mvc-4-application) which shows a sample bundle configuration:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo")
     .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1315/kendo.web.*") // or kendo.all.*
     .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1315/kendo.aspnetmvc.*")
);
```

The JavaScript files required by the grid can be found in the [JavaScript Dependencies](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies) help topic.

Answer (score 4):

Kendo's documentation does a good job of detailing dependencies for most controls, except for grid.  You can look in kendo.grid.min.js for the dependencies, but then you need to look in each of those files for *their* dependencies. So if you're building your dependencies without aid of a resource loader like require.js or system.js (my favorite), here's the full list for grid controls, in order:

```
/* Kendo Grid Dependencies */
kendo.core.min.js
kendo.data.min.js
kendo.userevents.min.js
kendo.window.min.js
kendo.draganddrop.min.js
kendo.columnsorter.min.js
kendo.filtermenu.min.js
kendo.columnmenu.min.js
kendo.groupable.min.js
kendo.pager.min.js
kendo.selectable.min.js
kendo.sortable.min.js
kendo.reorderable.min.js
kendo.resizable.min.js
kendo.mobile.actionsheet.min.js
kendo.mobile.pane.min.js
kendo.ooxml.min.js
kendo.excel.min.js
kendo.grid.min.js
```

Comment: Many of the grid dependencies you have listed are optional, depending on what features the OP is using. So it would be better to use kendo.all with require.js generate a custom kendo js file on the kendo website.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only kendo grid with all features, the problem is it depends on many smaller components. Its not a single file, however you can combine them all in a same file but I don't know it violates the law or not. Anyway, the list is as follows;

```
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.calendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.userevents.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.numerictextbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.binder.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.editable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.draganddrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.window.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.list.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.dropdownlist.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.filtermenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.menu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.columnmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.groupable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.filtercell.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.pager.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.selectable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.reorderable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.resizable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.fx.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.view.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.view.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.loader.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.pane.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.popover.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.mobile.actionsheet.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.ooxml.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.excel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.color.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.drawing.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.progressbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.columnsorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

I've included the angular.js and angular2 in the file list if you don't need those remove those. The total minified files come to 788KB compared to 2.7MB for kendo.all.min.js. Hope it helps.